# writing to a message router through a socket

Tags: java

i was trying to write a program by which i can write some messages to a MessageRouter through a socket.How can that be accomplished ? i have written the socket program to connect a client to the server through a socket.But will that actually do what i need..? By making the MessageRouter run on the server side ,can i accomplish my goal....?

Hope you have understood what my requirement is..?
Please do share any information you have regarding this.?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start from reading some tutorials, e.g.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html

When you finish reading and still have questions come back and ask. All guys will be happy to help you. Enjoy!

Comment: Alex, i had already gone through the tutorials and that was how i was able to write my socket program to connect a client and server...My question is how can i make use of that socket program to send messages to a MessageRouter ?